# When forward declaring classes should I use attribute defines there too?

Tags: c++, class, forward-declaration

When I'm forward declaring classes and I have a define like:

```
#define API __declspec(dllexport)
```

Should I declare the function with it, or without it? I know that I need to when I'm fully declaring the class (like, with a body and stuff), but I want to know if I should use it on forward declarations aswell.

Comment: The whole point of having something like `API` defined is so you can change it between `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)`, depending on the context. And it is impossible to put `__declspec(dllimport)` on a *definition*, since an imported symbol should not have its definition visible to the compiler—by definition. So this should always go on the declaration.

Comment: Ok, thank you, very useful. I do have 2 defines in there, but I only showed the one to make my point.

Comment: @CodyGray A class definition is a definition, and it does make sense to put `dllimport` there.

Answer (score 1):

In general my answer will be 'No'.

`__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)` attributes are needed only to know the fact "we need to export this" and "we need to import this".
And in places where only forward declaration is sufficient this fact doesn't matter because it means that in this place it's enough to know just that such class exists.

One of the most common use cases would be like this:

```
// --- Library ---
// Library.h
class LIBRARY_API LibraryClass
{
     void SomeMethod();
}

// Library.cpp
#include "Library.h" // we include the declaration together with __declspec(dllimport)
void LibraryClass::SomeMethod() { /*do something*/ }


// --- Some module which uses Library ---
// Some class .h file
class LibraryClass; // forward declaration
class SomeClass
{
    std::unique_ptr<LibraryClass> mp_lib_class; 
    // forward decl of LibraryClass is enough 
    // - compiler does not need to know anything about this class

    // ...   
}

// Some class .cpp file
#include <Library/Library.h> 
// here we include LibraryClass declaration with __declspec(dllimport)

//...
SomeClass::SomeClass()
    : mp_lib_class(std::make_unique<LibraryClass>())
        // here we need to actually call LibraryClass code
        // - and we know that it's imported because of #include
{}
```

And if you are forward declaring `LibraryClass` inside of a Library where it's actually defined - putting `__declspec(dllexport)` will not change anything because class is exported no matter of these forward declarations.